# JavaScript: Determine image type

Tags: javascript

I have an image:

```
<img src="https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQATogyQfWKBYKa-13DRJrXGruHezGarydPB-yDOw-rako27rV4">​
```

which displays as:

[image]​

The name of the image in the link exhibits no obvious extension. How can I use JavaScript to figure out what kind of image this is?

Comment: [This](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/html5/tutorials/determine-an-images-type-using-the-javascript-filereader.html#fbid=tUI6Ug5mWP7) could work (or some derivative thereof), but not tested. I saw it yesterday.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use a jquery ajax request like

```
var request = $.ajax({
  type: "HEAD",
  url: "/image_url", 
  success: function(){ 
    var ct = request.getResponseHeader("content-type") || "";
    if (ct.indexOf('jpg') > -1) {
      alert('Jpg');
    } ..
  }

});
```

Comment: What is `request` ( `var ct = request.get..` )?

Comment: XMLHttpRequest object. See: `var request = $.ajax(...`