# jquery check element file extension?

Tags: jquery

i need jquery to check what file type is contained in an element with a given ID. For example

```
<img id="e1" src="image.jpg" alt="">
<img id="e2" src="image.png" alt="">
<iframe id="e3" src="video.avi"></iframe>
<img id="e4" src="image.gif" alt="">
```

So basically i need jquery to tell me "e2" is a png so i can use it as a condition. I tried looking for a simple function that does that but i couldnt find anything. Could you please give me a hint?

Thank you.

Comment: you can use `.substr` with `.attr('src')` to get extension

Comment: `var isPNG = /\.png$/i.test(document.getElementById('e2').src);`

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript: Determine image type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13104446/javascript-determine-image-type)

Comment: The function you need is _so_ simple, you should write yourself [hint: `$(selector).attr('src').splt('.).pop()`.

Comment: Note that a file's extension is not a guarantee of its type. (It's not clear if a correct file extension is guaranteed in the OP's case.)

Comment: I tried moonwave99s code but i get an error saying $ is not defined. Why?

Comment: You don't have jQuery included?

Comment: I think i dont. Which version should i link to?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need wholly made specific functions when it can be done by simply using generic functions :

```
var isE2PNG = /\.png$/i.test(document.getElementById('e2').src);
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Use `.pop()` to get the extension.

```
var extension = $('#e2').attr('src').split('.').pop();

bool isPng = (extension.toLowerCase() == "png");
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function that will get the last three letters of the src attribute that are preceded by a dot:

```
function findFileExtension(jqElement){
    var filename = jqElement.attr('src');
    var extPattern = /\.\w{3}$/;
    return String(extPattern.exec(filename)).slice(1);
}
```

[See this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xn5TM/1/) for an example of how to use it.