# How do i make my discord recognize png from gifs?

Tags: javascript, bots, discord, discord.js, gif

Im trying to make my discord bot print out the user avatar but i dont know how to make the bot recignize if the authors avatar is png (or any other still image) or gif.

```
module.exports.run = async (bot, message, args) => {
  message.channel.send({files: [
{
  attachment: message.author.displayAvatarURL,
  name: "avatar.png"
}
]});
}
 module.exports.help = {
 name: "avatar"
}
```

Comment: See whether this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13104446/javascript-determine-image-type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As seen in the [discord.js documentation](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User?scrollTo=avatarURL), the property `avatarURL` from the `User` class provides the full URL to access the resource. That address probably includes the file's extension, which you could easily check with string methods like [.endsWith()](https://www.techonthenet.com/js/string_endswith.php).